# Ignoring .svn directory when executing a FlywayDB migrate

Tags: svn, flyway

I have a collection of SQL migration scripts that I deploy using the Flyway commandline utility.  Flyway will recursively search for any and all SQL scripts in the 'sql' root directory.  This is excellent behavior.  My project uses SVN for version control and thus .svn directories are littered all over everywhere. Ideally, I'd just point flyway to the directory with all my checked out migration scripts and just run the migration.

Is there a way to get Flyway to ignore the .svn directories?  I didn't see anything in the [documentation](http://flywaydb.org/documentation/commandline/migrate.html).

Answer (score 2):

I found out that Flyway is only looking for files ending in .sql.  As stored in the .svn directory, the scripts of interest end in .svn-base and are thus ignored by Flyway.  Works for me.